# about Search in Arrays

Tags: c

...........................................................................................................................................................
Hi everyone i got a little problem when i search for element in arrays
when i enter the number like 1007 he give me `Error: Invalid item ID` all the time

this is Myfile

1007 5 30

1004 4 10

1003 3 20

And this is my function

---

```
void DisplayItemInfoForAParticularItem(){
    FILE* f = fopen("items.txt", "r");
    int ItemID,ItemQuantity,PricePerUnit, i = 0,flag = 0;
    int ItemI[10], ItemQ[10],Price[10];

    while(fscanf(f,"%d%d%d",ItemI[i],ItemQ[i],Price[i]) != EOF){
        ++i;
    }
    printf("Enter itemID: ");
    scanf("%d",&ItemID);
    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
    {

        if(ItemI[i]==ItemID)
        {
            flag = 1;
            printf("ItemID  Quantity    Price Per Unit (SAR)");
            printf("%d  %d  %d",ItemI[i],ItemQ[i],Price[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
    if(flag==0)
    {
         printf("Error: Invalid item ID");
    }

    fclose(f);
   return ;
}
```

thank you for your help ............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fscanf()` is like `scanf()`, instead of scanning from `user` you are trying to scan from `file` but after scanning where you are storing ? `ItemI[i]` should be `&ItemI[i]` isn't it ?

```
 while(fscanf(f,"%d%d%d",&ItemI[i],&ItemQ[i],&Price[i])>0){
                ++i;
```

`Edit` : I think you want output in one way but you wrote in different way So I edited your code.

```
int DisplayItemInfoForAParticularItem(){
        FILE* f = fopen("items.txt", "r");
        if(f == 0) {
                printf("file is not present :\n");
                return 0;
        }
        int ItemID,ItemQuantity,PricePerUnit, i = 0,flag = 0;
        int ItemI[10], ItemQ[10],Price[10];

        while(fscanf(f,"%d%d%d",&ItemI[i],&ItemQ[i],&Price[i])>0){
                ++i;
        }

        for(i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
                printf("Enter itemID: ");
                scanf("%d",&ItemID);
                if(ItemI[i]==ItemID)
                {
                        flag = 1;
                        printf("ItemID  Quantity    Price Per Unit (SAR)\n");
                        printf("%d  %d  %d\n",ItemI[i],ItemQ[i],Price[i]);
                        break;
                }
                if(flag==0)
                {
                        printf("Error: Invalid item ID");
                }
        }
        fclose(f);
        return ;
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry i have 10 items Id

Comment: why we didn't say while(fscanf(f,"%d%d%d",&ItemI[i],&ItemQ[i],&Price[i]) != EOF){
                ++i;

Comment: because when fscanf() fails it returns -1 so when while(-1 > 0) it comes out

Comment: `fscanf` may fail because the input stream does not match the requested items, in which case it returns the number of items successfully read before the failure. Thus, when three items are requested, `fscanf` may return 3 (for success), 0, 1, or 2 (for a failure to convert one or more items), or `EOF` (for end of file or file error).

Comment: yes @EricPostpischil true. what you mentioned is there in man page of `fscanf()` in return value columns. `EOF` is returned either control reaches to end of file or any read error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Your code `fscanf(f,"%d%d%d",ItemI[i],ItemQ[i],Price[i])` passes the values of `ItemI[i]`, `ItemQ[i]`, and `Price[i]` to `fscanf`. However, `fscanf` needs to know the **addressess** of the objects so that it can store new values in them. Change that code to `fscanf(f, "%d%d%d", &ItemI[i], &ItemQ[i], &Price[i])`.

Additionally, do not rely on `fscanf` to return `EOF` when it fails. It may fail not because it reaches the end of the file but because it finds fewer than three numerals in the input that can be interpreted as integers, in which case it returns the number of items it converted before failing. So it could return 0, 1, or 2. Instead, you should check whether the return value of `fscanf` is equal to the number of items you want, 3.

Comment: No i have 10 items

Comment: (a) The format string `"%d%d%d"` requests three items. (b) I tried the changes, and they did work, except that my phrasing about the return value was unclear—`fscanf` returns 3 if it successfully read 3 items, so you want to continue the loop while the return value equals 3. (c) “It didn’t work” is not an adequate bug report. Report all the input data, the source code, the behavior you observed, and the behavior you expected.

Comment: `1007 5 30
1004 4 10
1003 3 20
1002 2 10
1006 4 40
1005 5 50
1001 1 70
1008 6 20
1010 4 90
1009 3 10`

Comment: this is my file

Comment: (a) “this is my file” is an inadequate bug report. Report **all** the input data (that in a file and that typed by the user), the source code, the behavior you observed, and the behavior you expected. (b) When I change the code by inserting `&` before each of the last three arguments to `fscanf` and changing `!= EOF` to `== 3` and adding a `main` routine and `#include <stdio.h>` and run it with either your original file contents or new file contents and enter an item ID, the program prints the item ID, quantity, and unit price for the item (albeit without aesthetic new-line characters).